# Develop a npm package based on old version code

Tags: javascript, git, npm

A npm package has old versions like `1.0.3` and new versions like `2.1.2`, I found there is a bug at version `1.0.3`, so I need to fix it and publish a new version `1.0.4`, so I need to get the code of `1.0.3`, but I found that there is no tag at the git repository, so how to do with this?

Comment: You have to find out what commit was used to release version `1.0.3`, there is no way around that. Having the source code for the release you can run `git diff` against the code and find the commit where the diff is minimal. Tag the found commit. Also create a branch from it an continue developing.

Comment: @phd I see, Thanks